# How can I programmatically receive faxes? Preferable in java

Tags: java, fax

I need to be able to receive a fax in a java application.  I was wondering what are some ways of doing this.  Efax?  Use a fax to email provider?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest using fax to email. I've been using [RapidFax](http://www.rapidfax.com) for the past year or so, and it is fairly inexpensive and fast. I'm happy with it.

Alternatively, there are some Web Service based fax services, like [InterFax](http://www.interfax.net).

Answer (score 1):

We use [Ringcentral.com](http://www.ringcentral.com) which sends the fax as a PDF to an email address.  We then access the PDF by accessing the POP3 account programatically (sp?).

Answer (score 1):

I use the fax-to-email capability of [101Fax](http://101fax.com/) and it has been rock-solid reliable.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done from Java on an API-accessible internet fax service such as Interfax. There are [Java fax](http://www.interfax.net/en/dev/java) samples available on their site for review and download.

Once you've signed up for inbound fax service (free for developers), download the jar file from any one of the code sample pages. The business end of receiving faxes into your application is the two following bits.

Let your app query the servers periodically for any new faxes that arrive for you, with method [GetList](http://www.interfax.net/en/dev/webservice/reference/getlist):

```
GetList parameters = new GetList(TestConstants.USERNAME,
                    TestConstants.PASSWORD,
                    ListType.AllMessages,    // Select the type of list you wish to return
                    10, // max items
                    new MessageItem[0]
                    );
```

Any fax sent to your number on the service will appear as a new record in the structure returned by this method. Once a new fax is available, you download it with method [GetImageChunk](http://www.interfax.net/en/dev/webservice/reference/getimagechunk):

```
GetImageChunk parameters = new GetImageChunk(TestConstants.USERNAME,
                        TestConstants.PASSWORD,
                        MESSAGE_ID,
                        MARK_AS_READ,
                        CHUNK_SIZE,
                        from,
                        new byte[0]
                        );
```